# Legally switching from 3DsMax to Blender

Tags: modeling, export

I'm trying to migrate my asset meshes from 3dsMax Student Edition to Blender so that I can ditch 3DsMax for Blender. I would like to do so legally for my non-commercial release of a project which will use these assets. Will exporting to an fbx file and importing into Blender remove any licensing data associated with my models from 3DsMax as I want it to be clean enough for public release from Blender. I once read that converting by exporting it to .obj format will clear it of any 3dsMax trace, but I am unsure.

If there is any simple solution it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about exporting from another software and licensing issues and not pertaining to Blender.

Comment: I would argue, however, that when the question is about exporting from another package for import *into* Blender, that it is on topic.

Answer (score 2):

I have unfamiliar with the any license or Terms of Service agreement of any edition of 3DS Max, and I am not a lawyer, and don't play one on the internet.

Having made those disclaimers, it is my understanding that the producers or Vendors of a software program do not have any legal interest in any output file (in this case a mesh) that you produce with your software. Just as Micro$oft does not have any intellectual property rights in a novel you create with their word processing software, the purveyors of 3DS Mas probably do not have any intellectual property rights in your meshes. The only exception of which I am aware to this general principle is if the file format to which you are exporting is proprietary, in which case the file format might be copyright. But even then, while the file format might be subject to copyright, that copyright applies to the file format, not the file content.

However, the format to which you expect to export, ~.obj, is an open format, and is not controlled by the purveyors of 3DS Max, so there is unlikely to be any associated licensing data.

ns