# Uniform Texture Page Repeat

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, uv, image

I am looking for a simple way to repeat part of a texture page uniformly over a large model. On the right you can see my texture page which I am using for multitexturing. On the left you can see the selected faces I have.

[image: My Map Model]

What I would like to do is unwrap the selected faces and have them collapse into a square that can fit correctly into the grass area. I also want the texture to repeat and flip horizontally and vertically. I do not want to unwrap it to some other shape and then scale it because this requires that I upsize the texture which is what I've done in other areas and the texture is now 10mb's as a result and far too inefficient for loading into any engine. The reset option under 'U' for unwrap comes close but the edges of the texture do not align properly but it does make a perfect square similar to what I want.

The game engine this is targeted for is GameMaker which does not support multi-texturing and I therefore must use a single combined texture. If there is a way I can achieve this without manually moving the texture coordinates and pinning them it would be really helpful, even if I could write a script or a plugin that could accomplish this to save me from having to do it by hand. It's theoretically possible but I doubt at this point that Blender has such built in features.

Edit: A clearer indication as to why the U->Reset feature does not work 100% notice towards the farthest left the edges of the triangle fan are not mapped correctly.

[image: Reset Option Not Perfect]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this will help you, but you could put them into different materials and then bake them out [like I explained here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32677/how-to-combine-two-different-textures-into-one/32682#32682)

Answer (score 2):

With the faces selected use <kbd>U</kbd> Unrwap to open the unwrap menu and chose *Reset*:

[image]

Result:

[image]

After that you can scale <kbd>S</kbd> and move <kbd>G</kbd> the uv as you like, use Circle select <kbd>C</kbd> to select all vertices in a corner and align them with your texture. 
Of course you can also align individual vertices.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, while this does work for pure rectangles this feature does not work perfectly when you introduce a triangle fan esque shape as I have selected in my original screen. This causes the border of triangles to not align properly and it is clearly noticeable, though not explicitly in my screen above because I do not have it highlighted. Please see second attached screenshot above.