# Combine Multiple Textures to Single UV Map

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, uv-image-editor

I currently am trying to import a 3D model that I got from somewhere else into Tabletop Simulator. For the most part, I have been able to make the progress I need, but I am at one last road block.

In blender, the character comes into 5 pieces. Hair, Body, Helmet, Weapon1, Weapon2. Each of these have their own texture. I am trying to get it to where They are one 'texture' for one 'object'.

So far, I have merged all 5 pieces into 1 using Ctrl-J. I press A and hit tab and unwrap everything. From there, I am stuck.

I have tried using the Bake method but I seem to be doing it wrong or its not the right thing for me. I create a New Image, Add it to a new UV Map, Give it a Material, and a Texture. I then go and I Bake 'texture' but all it does is seems to give me a black image with a bunch of islands. Here is what I attempted to copy.

[How to combine two different textures into one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32677/how-to-combine-two-different-textures-into-one)

I am wondering if maybe also Blender Render is the wrong window to be in for this?