# Extracting UV mapped image from 3 joined spheres with 2 different materials

Tags: materials, uv

I have created this molecule of CO2 by joining three different spheres and UV wrapping them individually. Now I want a single image of all the materials i used so that I can use it as a material in Unity. How do I do this?[image]

Comment: Try and search for Baking -> Selected to active. This is what you want. Basically you want to duplicate the Object with the 3 meshes, unwrap all 3 spheres together, create a new image in the image viewer and then bake "textures" and check selected to active.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15510/possible-to-bake-texture-to-new-uv-map, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32677/how-to-combine-two-different-textures-into-one. Also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake.