# How can I save my object's texture?

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv

How can I save my object's texture, for example in a .png file?

When I make a model I am using one body, but I am using different materials for the body's different faces. When I press the <kbd>A</kbd> button I can select all faces. How can I save all these face's textures, for example in a .png file?

I will edit this picture and add again in my body. I want this. How can I do that?

Comment: If you're talking about mixing several Image Textures, I think you can find an answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32677/how-to-combine-two-different-textures-into-one    If you're talking about something else I'm not sure about what it means and you should clarify

Comment: I think this [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90096/) will help you .