# How Can I bake multiple textures in the latest version of blender?

Tags: texturing, baking

I'm trying to combine a bunch of materials into one big texture and I came across this simple tutorial on baking (link at the bottom) which is exactly what I was looking for, but the version of blender in this tutorial is about 7 years old and the interface has changed a lot since then.  My bakes keep coming out black and I'm not sure which part I'm doing wrong.  All the tutorials I could find on youtube are about 20 minutes long and include a bunch of extra steps and manual placement of each texture, which isn't practical for me as I'm trying to combine 20+ materials.  If anyone could help me out or knows where I can find a simple baking tutorial on the latest version of blender it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

I have 20+ textures in each of my meshes, and due to the game engine I'm working with I have to set specs, bump maps, etc, tweak some values for each, and embed them all.  But doing this for all the materials on each of my meshes would take months.  So I'm trying to combine them into one big texture for each mesh so I can get it done in a matter of hours.

[How to combine two different textures into one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32677/how-to-combine-two-different-textures-into-one)

Comment: hello, the answer has been updated, but maybe describe your own project

Comment: Where can I find the updated answer? 

I have 20+ textures in each of my meshes, and due to the game engine I'm working with I have to set specs, bump maps, etc, tweak some values for each, and embed them all.  But doing this for all the materials on each of my meshes would take months.  So I'm trying to combine them into one big texture for each mesh so I can get it done in a matter of hours. Sorry for not being more clear, I'll add this to the end of my post

Comment: basically you need to duplicate your object (or join several objects into one object and duplicate this object), in the copy remove all material and UV maps, create a new material and unwrap again (Smart UV Project for example), in the material create an Image Texture with a new black image, then select the original object(s), shift copy the copy, bake with the option you want (I don't know the Combine option but it may be what you need), check the result